# How do I retrieve deleted photos from Windows Phone / Windows Phone Mass Storage

Tags: windows

I have a phone here that was accidentally restored to factory. It has pictures on it stored nowhere else.

I'd like to run Recuva on it to see if I can recover any deleted files, but it shows up in explorer as a device- it uses MTP, not mass storage.

Is it possible to somehow access the phone's memory as mass storage so I can run Recuva or other tools?

I have tried some registry edits found online but have had no success.

Edit: This is regarding Windows Phone 8.1 on a Lumia 920.

Comment: I believe this question might be more answerable if you state the exact model phone and operating system version. As it stands, it seems very broad, since any answer would have to account for all possibilities.

Comment: Windows Phone is pretty much identical across devices, but the device in question is a Lumia 920 with Windows Phone 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

If the photos were stored in your phone's internal memory, then there is very little chance of recovery after factory resetting. If the photos were stored in external SD card , then may be you can give it a shot by removing your SD card and connecting it to PC through a card reader or USB cable. If your card is detected, you can go ahead with recovery tools!

Comment: Sadly this particular model has no SD card. I'd love to be able to 'see' the internal storage in its entirety, as mass storage, to give recovery tools a go, but I'm not hopeful that this is at all possible.